# Python docstring type annotation -- a class, not an instance?

Tags: python, pycharm

Let's say I have:

```
class A(object):
   pass

class B(A):
   pass
```

I want to declare a function that takes a subclass of A as an argument:

```
def do_something(klass):
   """
   :type klass: WHAT_HERE
   """
   pass
```

What should I put in WHAT_HERE? If I make this:

```
:type klass: A
```

PyCharm thinks that I should give an instance of A as an argument, not the  class itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [pycharm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) as close as you can get is:

```
() -> SomeClass
```

So in your example

```
def do_something(klass):
   """
   :type klass: () -> A
   """
   pass
```

This means (for PyCharm) that the argument you are providing is a function that returns an object of a given type. It will properly type hint anything after the object creation.

Comment: Unfortunately this causes type inference problems in PyCharm for calling classmethods available on A. You can call `klass().klassmethod()`, but this instantiates the class, which may not be desirable. Thanks for the hint though, `() -> A` helps at least a little.

Answer (score 3):

Guido answered this question [here](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/58#issuecomment-194569410), but I believe PyCharm does not correctly support the appropriate syntax in Python 2. I believe the syntax should be `(...) -> A` in PyCharm with Python 2. In Python 3, the appropriate syntax is `Callable[..., A]`.

I note that PyCharm doesn't treat `() -> A` as a class either; if you call a classmethod on A using this syntax, PyCharm inspection will flag that it can't find the referenced classmethod.

This has been [filed in the JetBrains bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11615), though was closed based on earlier comments. Given Guido's recent comments in the first reference, I'm hoping JetBrains will reopen.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `Type`. If you have a `typing` module installed, you can also bound this class to be a subclass of something, like in following example:

```
class BaseUser(): pass        
class Admin(BaseUser): pass
class Staff(BaseUser): pass
class Client(BaseUser): pass
```

then

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

U = TypeVar('U', bound=BaseUser)

def new_user(user_class):
    """
    type user_class: Type[U]
    """
    return user_class()
```

and following are the usage

```
new_user(Admin)
new_user(Client)
new_user(Staff)
```

Pycharm | IDEA understand `typing` hints quite good, so it will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this using the docstring syntax for Python 2 in PyCharm or IDEA.

However, you can get code completion for the variable by placing an `assert` statement above the usage:

```
def call_foo(cls):
  """
  Calls the class method ``foo`` of the given class.

  :param cls: a subclass of SomeClass
  :type cls: type
  """
  assert issubclass(cls, SomeClass)
  cls.foo()  # you'll get code completion here for the foo method defined in SomeClass
```

Answer (score 0):

All classes are an instance of the `type` class:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> type(Foo())
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> type(Foo)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(Foo) is type
True
```

So, a valid answer would be:

```
:type klass: type
```

Comment: OK, but then it just says that it's *any* type. I'd like PyCharm to treat the argument as a subclass of A.

Comment: I'm afraid the only way would be to use a metaclass. But I'm not sure PyCharm supports it.